# pandas style options to latex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, latex, pandas-styles

Pandas has two nice functionalities I use a lot - that's the `df.style...` option and the `df.to_latex()` call. But I do not know how to combine both.

The .style option makes looking at tables much more pleasant.  It lets you grasp information rapidly because of visual enhancements. This works perfectly in a jupyter notebook, for example. Here is an arbitrary example I copied from the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html).

```
df.style.bar(subset=['A', 'B'], align='mid', color=['#d65f5f', '#5fba7d'])
```

This yields:

[image: Dataframe with style columns]

However, as nice as this looks in a jupyter notebook, I can not put this to latex code. I get the following error message instead, if chaining a 'to_latex()' call at the end of my visual enhancements: `AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute`. Does that mean it's simply not possible, because the displayed colorful table is not a DataFrame object any more, but now a Styler object, now?

Is there any workaround? At least with easier tables, let's say where only cells have a single background color with respect to their value, instead of a 'complicated' bar graph.

Comment: Chaining `to_latex()` at the end of that call won't work because at that point it's a `Styler` object, not a dataframe. Have you tried using `df.style.apply()` then calling `df.to_latex()`? Or reassign the styled dataframe to an object then call `to_latex()`

Comment: There's an open PR for this: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21673

Answer (score 2):

As of pandas v1.3.0 these are now combined in [`pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.to_latex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.to_latex.html).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to export this formatting to bulky LaTeX markup, I would go the route explored already over in TeX.SE: add the functionality as LaTeX code that draws similar formatting based on the same data.

- Red/green value bars:
  [Partially coloring cell background with histograms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81994/partially-coloring-cell-background-with-histograms)
- Coloured cell backgrounds:
  [Are there an easy way to coloring tables depending on the value in each cell?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174998/30821)
- Shaded backgrounds (similar, but points to excellent package `pgfplotstable`):
  [Parametrize shading in table through TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42444/parametrize-shading-in-table-through-tikz)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you can use latex directly but you can use df.to_html(). Once you get the html you can style it as you like and then use any of the following.

1. [Python's html2latex](https://pypi.org/project/html2latex/)
2. [Website :HTML to TEX Converter](https://cloudconvert.com/html-to-tex)
3. [Python's weasyprint](https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)
4. Pandoc

Here is one latex package that I found on googling that talks about embedding html in latex.
https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/latex/use-html-package-in-latex-control-your-output/

I once only used latex and embedded images of tables when I used it.